# How to use an count function as a condition in case statement in django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

```
`SELECT id,name,(case WHEN (status<>"COM" AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BAC WHERE (BAC.status<>"AM" AND CURDATE() > BAC.deadline AND  BAC.act_id=Act.id) )>0 )THEN 6) as status FROM ACT)
```

> Models

```
class ACT(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class BAC(models.Model):
status = models.CharField(max_length=5)
act = models.ForeignKey(ACT,on_delete=models.CASCADE())
```

`I am facing the problem of converting a MySQL query to Django ORM. I am trying to assign a value to a field when the count of some values in another field increases than a certain value.

Comment: Can You please share the related models?

Comment: At first sight, the subquery does not make much sense, since it does not depend on the outer query.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know your exact models I am just creating a random example. I hope this helps.

```py
class Boo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Hoo(models.Model):
    boo = models.ForeignKey(Boo)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

Hoo.objects.filter(
    name='boohoo'
).annotate(
    count=Count(Case(When(boo__name='boo', then=1)))
)
```

What this code will do is for every `Hoo` object with `name=boohoo` it will annotate a `count` field which will be the `Count` of their related `Boo` class, when `boo__name='boo'`

Comment: my requirement is to apply the When condition on the result of count function. let's say Count of their related Boo class when boo__name='boo' is greater than 10

Comment: By any chance, can you post your models or an example of your relations in the question?

Comment: models are added and the query is changed.